Traslado de columnas entre tablas por criterios
Tengo las siguientes tablas:


Lo que quiero hacer es agregar en la tabla2 los valores de la tabla1 correspondiente a la var1.
Lo que pensé es seleccionar una subtabla de la tabla1 para los ID iguales en ambas tablas. Luego seleccionar la columna var1 de esa nueva tabla y agregarla a la tabla2.
Este es el código que llevo:
tabla1 = pd.DataFrame()
tabla1['ID'] = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5']
tabla1['var1'] = [1,0,1,1,0]
tabla1['var2'] = ['Sí','No','No','No','Sí']

tabla2 = pd.DataFrame()
tabla2['ID'] = ['id2','id1','id5']
tabla2['var3'] = [0,1,3]
tabla2['var4'] = ['Sur','Norte','Norte']

# esto es para hacer la seleccion de la tabla1 por el criterio de los ID
tabla1[tabla1['ID'] == tabla2['ID'].tolist()]

pero me tira el siguiente error:

ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (3,))

Si pudieran ayudarme con eso, por favor.

En base a esto:

Lo que quiero hacer es agregar en la tabla2 los valores de la tabla1 correspondiente a la var1.

Una solución es utilizar merge(), indicando:

how igual a inner.
on igual a ID.

Ejemplo:
import pandas as pd

tabla1 = pd.DataFrame()
tabla1['ID'] = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5']
tabla1['var1'] = [1,0,1,1,0]
tabla1['var2'] = ['Sí','No','No','No','Sí']

tabla2 = pd.DataFrame()
tabla2['ID'] = ['id2','id1','id5']
tabla2['var3'] = [0,1,3]
tabla2['var4'] = ['Sur','Norte','Norte']

tabla3 = tabla2.merge(tabla1, how='inner', on='ID')

print(tabla3)

Salida:
    ID  var3   var4  var1 var2
0  id2     0    Sur     0   No
1  id1     1  Norte     1   Sí
2  id5     3  Norte     0   Sí

Demo

Para obtener el mismo resultado pero excluyendo, por ejemplo var2, tenes que indicar las columnas a incluir de tabla1:
tabla3 = tabla2.merge(tabla1[['ID', 'var1']], how='inner', on='ID')

Resultado:
    ID  var3   var4  var1
0  id2     0    Sur     0
1  id1     1  Norte     1
2  id5     3  Norte     0

Demo

Muchas gracias Marcos !!!
Es justo lo que necesitaba !!!

Hola @Andres, si mi respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada y/o votarla. Saludos
